# Is it possible to hide inline html/css coding from a parser?

Tags: html, css, inline

Is there some trick that would allow one to hide the **inline coding** itself but which would not also make the **content** invisible/hidden?

The context: A commercial site I use allows limited inline coding for its members. For example, I can use `<font color="blue">` to change the color of my username on the site. Likewise, css's hidden/visible/display/etc work.

These work fine in **most** places. But in other places, the actual inline coding *itself* appears and, using my example, my name appears as `<font color="blue">`Phantom`</font>` (in black text) - obviously not the desired result.

So the site parses inline coding in *some* areas but simply passes it along as output text in *other* areas (sigh). It would actually be preferable, in this case, to have the inline coding simply be ignored/deleted rather than show in the output.

I don't think that hmtl and/or css has an answer for this?  I am hoping that some ingenious person knows a trick that can be entered as inline code that will (gulp) hide that very inline coding on those occasions when it will not be parsed.

Is there a way?

**Edit:**

Andre (and everyone else), I apologize - I thought the example I posted was sufficient.  I also see that some of what I had entered did not display properly (corrected). Let me try again.

On a website where I have the user name "Phantom",  I can enter my user name as `<font color = "blue">`Phantom`</font>`).

- My name in **most** places correctly appears as: [Phantom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTTEz.png).
- However in other places, my name appears as: **<font color = "blue">Phantom<font>**

Is there a way to make my name appear with blue text where it is currently blue... but then have it appear in the default black **without** the inline coding in the areas where html/css coding is not parsed?

I am pretty confident that this is impossible - if the inline coding is **not** parsed, then there is nothing I could put in that would affect the output. But in case someone with a deeper understanding of parsing engines might have an idea, I am opening myself up to be scoffed at.  I know. I know. Forget about it!

Comment: What do you actually mean by `inline coding`?

Comment: I do not understand. `</font color="blue"/>` is html it is not css.

Comment: In a normal html document, you can declare CSS using the `link tag` (as external resource). Or the `style tag` (not only in the head! but anywhere in the DOM) or with the `style property` in an html tag. Is that last one the one that you mean as inline coding?

Comment: forget about it. it is not important

Answer (score 0):

I should say that i dont think i understood your question 100%. However all inline html codes will be executed by the browser if syntax is correct and the browser is capable, you only can overwrite them with other codes.

Also inline styling rules will overwrite css rules.

Also if your concern is sensitive data, then **what ever you do ** html is open source.

Editing your question by the way with A clear example for your intention will help you more.

Comment: Please leave comments if you did not understand the OP's question well as I dont think someone did